# Can't see created disk partition when installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I am trying install Ubuntu on dualboot with win10. I had a four disk partition - System, HP-Tools, HP-Recovery and C. I can't create disk partition when installing Ubuntu so I thought I will create new partition from Windows and then divide to disks for ubuntu when installing. But I can't see this new partition in ubuntu installation. There are only 4 partition from the beginning of my post.

All partition are dynamics. Are there any steps how install ubuntu on the new partition?

Thanks for reply

**UPDATED**

[This is my partitons in windows disk manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/truWP.png)

[This is in gparted, there is sda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSTAY.png)

Don't know what is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSDOS partition table only supports 4 primary partitions.  To have more than that, you need to create an extended partition and then create logical partitions inside that.  Recent versions of Windows tend to steer you towards converting the disk to a "dynamic disk" instead of using extended partitions when you try to create more than 4 primary partitions.  This is not compatible with linux.  If windows sees the disk as a dynamic disk, you will need to delete the partition, convert the disk back to a basic disk, delete one of the 4 primary partitions, and reuse that space as an extended partition.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am not sure if understand good, but I deleted one of the partition, so now I have three - check my update post. I thought it will be ok create in ubuntu install or gparted new extended but it is not working. I have there weird partitions with weird sizes. If it is because of dynamic partitions so will I delete all my patitions, it means recovery win? It is realy idiotic...

Comment: @Bulva, you need to use the windows disk manager to convert the disk back to a basic disk, like I said.

Comment: Thanks for help I format harddisk and install clean install win7 and Ubuntu. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Try using gparted to reformat the partition from the live-cd/usb

```
apt-get install gparted
```

Comment: I tried to use gparted but there is not new partition too. Only that four in my post.

Comment: Can you see the disk with: "sudo fdisk -l" ?

Comment: No, it is not there, but i noticed at night that in gparted is in my C disk unused spaced which is the same as the new created partition. Check my updated post.